# Communicaiting with java server in objective-c

Tags: java, iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I'm working on the app where i have to send one Hexadecimal string to the server and server send me response back in same hexastring.

I tried using ASIHTTP and simple NSURL connection (Hit and trail ;-)) It was not working at all . I tried to find in Google like communication with java server but didn't found anything useful.

any help , how we can send hexa string to java server in objective-c

What i tried:

```
NSString * strURL = KbaseURL;
ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: strURL]];
[request setDelegate: self];

//[request setPostValue:_hexString forKey:nil];

[request setPostBodyFilePath:_hexString];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: _It was not working at all_ Why? What didn't work? What did you expect? Can you please show us the code you used?

Comment: Sure 
 NSString *strURL =KbaseURL ;
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
     //[request setPostValue:_hexString forKey:nil];
    [request setPostBodyFilePath:_hexString];
    
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request startAsynchronous];

This way i tried in ASIHTTP method

Comment: I added your code to the question, feel free to re-format it if it's formatted wrong, i'm not familiar with Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are sending the value with a nil key, you should set a key for it. And you need to receive it through the webservice , the webservice url should be the KbaseURL.

Comment: Actually its a Java server and posting hexa key to server is without key . Base url is simple URL "http://xyz.co.in/servlet".
and i have to POST a key that's it

Answer (score 0):

Ok it worked with ASIHTTP method

All I have to do is:

```
[ request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setPostBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:[_hexString  dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]]; // where hexstring is hexa decimal string
```

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted so that you get reputation and your question is removed from **Unanswered** list.